# Density operator in canonical quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator, second-quantization

I often see that the density operator in $1^{st}$ quantization is defined to be:
$$ \hat n(\vec r)=\sum_{i=1}^N \delta(r-\hat r_i)$$

In canonical quantization it is given by $$ \hat n(\vec r)=\hat \psi^\dagger(\vec r)\hat\psi(\vec r)$$ but shouldn't there be a factor of $N$ multiplying since in the definition of the expectation value of $\hat n$, we act with $\delta(r-\hat r_i)$ on the ket $N$ times?

Answer (score 1):

It may be tricky to explain why it is so (because it essentially means explaining the second quantization), but note that this is the case for *all* the single-particle operators! For example, the kinetic energy of a collection of identical particles in the first quantization is $$\hat{K} = \sum_i\frac{\hat{p}_i^2}{2m},$$ and becomes in the second quantization
$$\mathcal{\hat{K}} = \int dx \psi^\dagger(x)\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}\psi(x).$$